# Order by expression

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I do the following:

```
select * from table order by istrue(field > 90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `istrue()` do?  I don't recognize it as a MySQL function.

Perhaps your intention is to order things so the values of `field` greater than 90 are first.  If so:

```
order by (field > 90) desc
```

In a numeric context, MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers with "1" being true.  Hence the `desc` to get the true values first.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think OP did not intent to show `istrue` as a function, but instead as a requirement. Still, this answer is good, I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

use `Case` statement;

```
select * from table 
         order by 
               case when field > 90 then ordercolumn end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what your trying to achieve is this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > 90 ORDER BY field
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY (field > 90) DESC
```

Or maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > 90 ORDER BY field DESC
```